# Mixes of candy probability question

Tags: probability

How many different mixes of candy are possible if a mix consists of 10 pieces of candy and 4 different kinds of candy are available in unlimited quantities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic stars-and-bars question.

There are 4 types of candy, let them be A, B, C, D. Now imagine 10 similar pieces of candy on a line, and then we will put 3 bars in between them. The ones left to the first bar will be of type A, and then B, C, D going to the right, changing iff a bar is hit. This process is clearly reversible. So there will be 13 items in all, 10 of one type, 3 of another type. Hence there are 13C3=286 possible combinations.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how 13C3 was obtained? I pictured the problem in a little different way. I thought we were choosing 10 pieces of candy from 4 different types of candy. Wouldn't we have 4 choices for the first piece of candy, 10 choices for the second piece and so on?

Comment: Yes, if order matters, then of course there will be 4^10 ways. However, in how I interpreted this question, the order does not matter, so A, A, A, B, B, ..., B is the same as B, B, ..., B, A, A, A. Do you need a clarification on my method or I understood the question wrongly?

Comment: I'm sure you understood the question correctly. I'm just having trouble understanding the answer. =( Sorry. Some more clarification would be great :)

Comment: Okay. So let's do it like this. For example if we have 10 candies and 3 bars. Then we arrange that in any order. The candies before the first bar becomes in A, the ones in between the first and second bar becomes B, between the second and third bar becomes C, and the ones after the third bar becomes D. So if we have a certain arrangement of candies and bars, we will have a set of candies. Similarly, this process is reversible, so if we have a set of candies, we can have an arrangement of candies and bars. 13 items, split into 10 and 3 (of diff. kinds), so ans is 13C3=286.